How does SwiftUI automatically size an UIImage?
I'm a beginner learning SwiftUI
I have a simple blue bitmap file imported into asset. it's a bmp file that's 150x150 pixels
I create a UIImage by:
let data = NSDataAsset(name: "BitmapBlue150")!.data
        
        
let uiImage = UIImage(data: data)!

Then in my view the bitmap is shown by
Image(uiImage: uiImage)

When I check uiImage.scale, it is showing scale = 1
However, it seems to me that the displayed image is 150x150 points, not pixels
Did the Image view automatically scale the image? if it did, then the scale factor shouldn't be 1, right?
Thank you for any insight

You misunderstood how scale works. The scale of an image is the factor you multiply by, to convert from points to pixels.

If you load an image from a file whose name includes the @2x modifier, the scale is set to 2.0. You can also specify an explicit scale factor when initializing an image from a Core Graphics image. All other images are assumed to have a scale factor of 1.0.
If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the size property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the image in pixels.

So a scale of 1.0 means one pixel in the image corresponds to one point, and yes, iOS will automatically resize the image depending on the scale of the device's screen. Since one pixel of your image corresponds to one point, the image will get scaled up by a factor of 3 if you display it on an iPhone 15 Pro Max (scale=3, i.e. three pixels per point).
The scale of your image is 1.0, simply because you did not specify a scale: when creating the image. The Data you passed to init(data:) has no scale, and so a scale of 1.0 is assumed. If you do UIImage(data: data, scale: 2.0) for example, you can set the scale yourself.
If you used an image set instead of a data set, you can set the scale of an image by putting them in the corresponding slots:

The system will then select the appropriate version of the image depending on the device.
